# Why does the side of two magnet attract?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have two magnetic bars and when they are brought close sideway the two bars join where the two South poles are adjacent to each other, and so does the two North poles. If the magnetic field goes from South to North and repel when is the same pole, why doesn't the magnetic bar rotate and align itself to NSNS?

[image]

Comment: If the two magnets have the same strength, I believe this should not happen. Perhaps one is significantly stronger than the other, and it may in effect demagnetize it and reverse its polarization?

Comment: Are you sure that the two magnets are parallel? If you put them anti-parallel (i.e. N of one parallel to S of the other and vice-versa), then they will attract strongly.

Comment: are you sure poles are as you think in your magnets ? nowadays poles can be on quite arbitrary places on bricks / cylinders / spheres/plate magnets.

Answer (score -1):

yes i also have seen the same thing

i had two same magnets whose shape was as that of cylinder but with the ends curved and it may look like extremely stretched egg.

anway if i throw them both in the air they will attract and stick towards each other horizontally

i am very confused by that if their poles are at the ends

but if their poles are not at the end of their lengths but along the middle portion , that may explain the observation

Comment: Op is asking about why this phenomenon occurred? Please answer corresponding the question. It will help the users who read your answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/382499)